# how do you pass sodipodi as an attribute with xml_file_open in php?

Tags: php, xml, svg

what my program effectively is attempting to do is grab data from an xml file (that used to be an svg file). and with this grab the relevant information from the xml tags as attributes and values. 
I have my php set like this

```
foreach($xml_file_open->g->path[0]->attributes() as $attribute => $value)
{
echo $attribute => $value
}
```

and the output for the xml_file_open attributes request is

```
style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;
stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:
miter;stroke-opacity:1"
id="path2987"
d="m 631.42859,603.79077 a 212.85715,162.85715 0 1 1
-425.7143,0 212.85715,162.85715 0 1 1 425.7143,0 z"
```

(3 lines with style and d being intentionally split for readability)
whereas instead of getting those 3 lines of data I am attempting to get everything within this  tag

```
<path
   sodipodi:type="arc"
   style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;
stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="path2987"
   sodipodi:cx="418.57144"
   sodipodi:cy="603.79077"
   sodipodi:rx="212.85715"
   sodipodi:ry="162.85715"
   d="m 631.42859,603.79077 a 212.85715,162.85715 0 1 1
 -425.7143,0 212.85715,162.85715 0 1 1 425.7143,0 z" />
```

it seems to be the sodipodi: that it won't read as an attribute, how would I get it to read sodipodi:cx/cy etc as an attribute?

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2010/10/resetting-namespaced-attributes-using-simplexml/) of mine might be useful, although it is for SimpleXML.

Comment: to be honest that gave me the concept but I found the answer here.
http://www.leftontheweb.com/message/A_small_SimpleXML_gotcha_with_name_spaces

Comment: Np, glad it was of partial service! `:)` (that link doesn't work btw, it's [here](http://leftontheweb.com/message/A_small_SimpleXML_gotcha_with_namespaces)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the namespace URI to the attributes method to access prefixed attributes:

```
$attrs = $node->attributes('http://inkscape.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd');
echo $attrs['cx'];
```

More info at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: just to make sure (sorry for the long reply time) the atributes () namespace in between the () can be custom made? so since I am trying to get sodipodi I could make a file for the namespace sodipodi? not entirely sure how I would do that to be honest (fairly new to programming, forgive me for being noobish) 

effectively I am trying to have it print out the attribute, then value so I can store it in an array(should have worded this a bit better) but I think if I have how you can create the namespace url cleared up (googled and found nothing)I would be able to work past that.great link halfer)

Answer (score 1):

The "sodipodi:"-part of the attribute name is the namespace prefix. How do you read the XML? If you use the DOM API the prefix is available [through the DOMNode class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.prefix).

Comment: I read the xml file through       $xml_file_open = simplexml_load_file("svgboard.xml"); (after changing the file from an svg file to an xml file)
not quite seeing how I would implement that to display everything from the path tag. I think I should have rephrased my question to say "how do I get the foreach loop to not skip over tags with a namespace prefix". thanks for your help, its probably much simpler than I am making it out to be, I am just quite tired.